# want to hide or remove or replace comment "Applet Started"

Tags: java, applet

hii to all

I want to hide or display or replace comment 'Applet Started'
which display at left bottom of the applet start page
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't: as a security measure, all applets must be visually identified as such.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a speculation, but couldn't you overwrite it with a status message?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [link](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5127507).

> I just solved it actually by setting in the <Applet .... tag the Name= property ...Now the Applet name is consistent across browsers.

Otherwise try repeatedly calling:

```
getAppletContext().showStatus("");
```

As described on [jGuru](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=487929).

Comment: no it doesnt work.....

Applet tag means Applet viewer tag?.....

by the way where i have to write Applet tag